# Rounding Off Decimal Value to Pevious and Next Hundreds

Tags: c#-3.0

I am working in C#. I have decimal variable startFilter that contains value say 66.76. Now I want this decimal value to appear in the seach filter $0 to $100. But what I also want is, that the search filter starts from the first decimal value that comes in startFilter variable. So for instance in this case the search filter will start from $0 to $100 because the value in startFilter variable is 66.76, but in another case it can be $100 to $200 if the first value that comes in searchFilter is say $105.

Having said that, how should I round off the value in seachFilter to previous hundreds and the next hundreds. Like if the value is 66.76 it rounds off to 0 as floor and 100 as ceiling, so on and so forth.

Any idea how to do that in C#?

Answer (score 3):

```
double value = ...
int rounded = ((int) Math.Round(value / 100.0)) * 100;
```

Comment: Rounding is not the same as taking floor/ceiling.

Answer (score 2):

divide your original number by 100. get floor and celing values. Multiply each of them by 100.